# Unescape Hex code point \u0026 without altering the encoding in Python

Tags: python, encoding, web-scraping, scrapy, hex

While scraping, I'm getting hex code point in the extracted data like \u0026#39; and \u003c. The problem is while extracting, they are getting escaped by getting a "\" before them like \\u0026#39 and \\u003c. So to tackle that I used,

```
Tag = response.xpath("//script[contains(.,'" + SplitString + "')]").extract()
Tag = Tag[0].split(SplitString)
Tag = Tag[1].split("\"]")
Tag = codecs.getdecoder('unicode_escape')(Tag[0])[0]
```

But the problem with using "unicode_escape" is that it alters some special symbols like ❤️❤️ and converting it into Ã°ÂŸÂŽÂˆÃ¢ÂÂ¤Ã¯Â¸ÂÃ°ÂŸÂŽÂˆÃ¢ÂÂ¤Ã¯Â¸ÂÃ°ÂŸÂŽÂˆ. So how do I tackle that?

The script from the source code is like:

```
<script nonce="q0OGvOrA73kvqp+Tk1lGIR+glJc">AF_initDataCallback({key: 'ds:4', isError:  false , hash: '17', data:function(){return [[["Machineship"]
,null,null,[1]
,null,[["CBSqARUKEwiZjNDE8bDcAhWKI2gKHV8ZDtA\u003d"]
,["CBSqARUKEwiYjNDE8bDcAhWKI2gKHV8ZDtA\u003d"]],[[null,"Enjoy different kind of magazines and entertainment\u003cbr\u003e3 on the various supported classic rule.\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e[Feature]\u003cbr\u003e- 1 to max 4 can join\u003cbr\u003e- You can select one of three different patterns.\u003cbr\u003e- :\u003cbr\u003ehttps://www.example.com"]
,[null,"Best \u0026quot;ad-free\u0026quot; entertainment for kids!\u003cbr\u003e❤️❤️"]
]
,null,[[[null,2,[800,1200]............... </script>
```

and from this I want to extract : Best "ad-free" entertainment for kids!
❤️❤️

Comment: What does `SplitString` refer to? What do you do with tag after it's set? Can you provide a short working example of the problem, I'll try to replicate the problem to see what's happening.

Comment: SplitString is a combination of characters which is first getting used to find that particular combination out of a script tag from a website and then to split the text out of that node or specifically SplitSrting = ("]\n,[bullpup,)

Comment: I wrote a quick scraper that read `&#39;❤️❤️` from a `div` on a site, I had no problem writing that to a file. I can't see where you're getting `\\u` added, but all I think you'd need to do is remove one of the slashes from each occurrence in a string. If you add a script to the question that replicates your issue, I might be able to see what's happening.

Comment: have added the snippet of the script.

Comment: To clarify what would you enter for SplitString for that example?

Comment: m"]
,[null," and that would translate to (m"]\n,[null,") with escape sequence as "m\"]\n,[null,\""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tag.encode('utf-8')` to encode the string correctly this returns bytes which means you must then use `wb` when writing to the file *eg* `f = open('filename, 'wb')`. The below script now encodes the string.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

body = '<script nonce="q0OGvOrA73kvqp+Tk1lGIR+glJc">AF_initDataCallback({key: \'ds:4\', isError:  false , hash: \'17\', data:function(){return [[["Machineship"]\n,null,null,[1]\n,null,[["CBSqARUKEwiZjNDE8bDcAhWKI2gKHV8ZDtA\u003d"]\n,["CBSqARUKEwiYjNDE8bDcAhWKI2gKHV8ZDtA\u003d"]],[[null,"Enjoy different kind of magazines and entertainment\u003cbr\u003e3 on the various supported classic rule.\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e[Feature]\u003cbr\u003e- 1 to max 4 can join\u003cbr\u003e- You can select one of three different patterns.\u003cbr\u003e- :\u003cbr\u003ehttps://www.example.com"]\n,[null,"Best \u0026quot;ad-free\u0026quot; entertainment for kids!\u003cbr\u003e❤️❤️"]\n]\n,null,[[[null,2,[800,1200]............... </script>'

split_string = 'm"]\n,[null,"'

tag = Selector(text=body).xpath("//script[contains(.,'" + split_string + "')]").extract()

tag = tag[0].split(split_string)
tag = tag[1].split("\"]")
tag = tag[0]

f = open('test.txt', 'wb')
tag = tag.encode('utf-8')
f.write(tag)
f.close()

print('done')
```

It prints: `Best &quot;ad-free&quot; entertainment for kids!<br>❤️❤️`

I'm not sure where you are getting the double slashes from, but they may actually be needed to escape the slashes in the string, so may not pose a problem.

Comment: Sir, but when I do that it Shows as Best \u0026quot;ad-free\u0026quot; entertainment for kids!\u003cbr\u003e❤️❤️ in the terminal and the same get exported to the csv. Also, it must be noted that when I try to print such strings in sublime then it auto-corrects them to serve the correct results. Currently I'm using replace as Tag.replace("\\u0026", "&").replace("\\u003c", "<").replace("\\u003e", ">").

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at this? I've updated my answer and think it'll work for you.